# Return Bootstrap .navbar-toggle to its normal state after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap v3.3.4 out of the box, no custom CSS.

When clicking on the hamburger button, the navigation expands as it's supposed to, although the button itself stays in a "pressed" mode and only returns to its normal state when clicking elsewhere on the page.

Anyone know how to make the hamburger button return to its normal state right after it gets clicked?

This is the button I'm referring to, to avoid confusion:

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse">...
```

Comment: do you have an example for us?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the button keeps focus, and bootstrap styles for that.

Change the styles for the pseudo selector `:focus`:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Note you will want to re-apply your `:hover` styles, as the `:focus` styles will take precedence when the button is both focused and hovered:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover{
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/rINvQCH5iM)